# Почему Dictionary, при одинаковых хешах не выдает значение

Tags: c#, словари

у меня есть следующий код в игре на unity

```
    public Spell GetSpell(ElementsQueue<Elements> magicCombination)
    {
        Debug.Log("magicCombination hash: " + magicCombination.GetHashCode());
        Debug.Log("magicCombination hash: " + meteorCastCombination.GetHashCode());
        Debug.Log(_spellsDictionaty.ContainsKey(magicCombination));
        Debug.Log(_spellsDictionaty.ContainsKey(meteorCastCombination));

        return _spellsDictionaty[magicCombination];
    }
```

В результате, при выполеннии метода `GetSpell` я в консоле вижу такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как такое вообще возможно? Хеш этих объектов  же одинаковый

Comment: хеш используется для быстрого поиска ключа, но это не значит, что сами ключи не будут сравниваться. Почитайте про коллизии

Comment: А еще 80 - не особо толковое значение для хэша. ¿Вы там случаем ничего не переопределяете?

Comment: Спасибо большое, странно, я и забыл что GetHeshCode и Equals должны идти парой. Не волнуйтесь, 80 - это тестовое значение, спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 0):

если переопределяется метод  Equals , то также необходимо переопределить и метод  GetHashCode . Дело в том, что эти методы связаны контрактом, и при переопределении одного метода нужно так же переопределить и другой.

Дело в том, что методы  Equals и  GetHashCode необходимы для корректной работы разных коллекций, в частности, Hashtable и Dictionary<TKey,TValue> и других. Хэштаблица — это коллекция, в которой каждый элемент представляет из себя пару «ключ-значение». Для того, чтобы реализовать такую коллекцию, нам необходима операция сравнения. А для того, чтобы такая коллекция работала быстро, нам также необходима возможность получить хэшкод объекта ключа.